# Reference request for a subfamily of regular graphs

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request

I'm looking for literature on the following "nice" family of graphs:

Call a regular graph $G=(V,E)$ (of regularity degree $d$) **nice** if there exists a coloring $C:V\to \{ 1,\dots,d \}$ such that each vertex $v$ has precisely one neighbour of each color.

By double counting $\{(x,y):x\sim y, C(y)=i\}$ we see that in a nice graph we have $d\mid n = |V|$ and each color appears on $n/d$ vertices.

This is not sufficient, as a $6$ cycle is $2$ regular but not nice.

An example of a nice graph: $V=\{0,1\}^8$, $x\sim y$ iff they differ in precisely one bit (Hamming distance 1). The coloring of $(x_0,\dots,x_7)$ is $(x_0\cdot 0)\oplus (x_1\cdot 1) \oplus \dots \oplus (x_7\cdot 7)$, with $\oplus$ denoting xor. (Of course $8$ can be replaced with any power of two).

In particular, I am wondering when the graph ($V=S_n$, $x\sim y$ iff $y=x\tau$ for some transposition $\tau$) is nice.

Comment: The following might be interesting:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X14001186
This is not exactly what you want, but these Grundy colorings seem to be related.